# md-table - How to update the column width

Tags: angular

I have started using the md-table for my project, and I want fixed column width. Currently all columns width are divided into equal size.

Where can I get the documentation of data table dimensions?

https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview

Answer (score 142):

When Material creates the table it automagically applies two class-names for you which you can use to style each column.
In the the example below the styles is named `mat-column-userId` and `cdk-column-userId`.

```
<ng-container cdkColumnDef="userId">
  <md-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef> ID </md-header-cell>
  <md-cell *cdkCellDef="let row"> {{row.id}} </md-cell>
</ng-container>
```

Now you can use those names in css:

```
.mat-column-userId {
  flex: 0 0 100px;
}
```

Similar to [Rahul Patil's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45159710/1380772), but you don't need to add another class to your column definitions.

Comment: In my case I needed !important for styles applied like this because otherwise the style for `.mat-header-cell` would take precedence. Alternatively, you could just add another style rule for the header cell.

Comment: Is the documentation for this available anywhere (I wanted to understand what each of the 3 values after "flex" meant and how .mat-column-<colName> referred to the corresponding column)? Thanks!

Comment: @RahulSaha flex is now a standard css property: "This is a shorthand property that sets flex-grow, flex-shrink, and flex-basis." source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex

Comment: This is the solution I ended up using, but instead of setting the flex basis I set flex grow so the cell is 3x larger than other cells (flex: 3 0 0)

Comment: Setting width with flex did not work in my case.  Neither did width.  min-width did (for some reason).

Comment: @jymdman is there any way to define same size for the column even screen size changes? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65296518/how-to-support-same-column-size-when-screen-size-reducing-in-angular-material-ta

Answer (score 56):

Right now, it has not been exposed at API level yet. However you can achieve it using something similar to this

```
<ng-container cdkColumnDef="userId" >
  <md-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef [ngClass]="'customWidthClass'"> ID </md-header-cell>
  <md-cell *cdkCellDef="let row" [ngClass]="'customWidthClass'"> {{row.id}} </md-cell>
</ng-container>
```

In css, you need to add this custom class -

```
.customWidthClass{
   flex: 0 0 75px;
}
```

Feel free to enter the logic to append class or custom width in here. It will apply custom width for the column.

Since md-table uses `flex`, we need to give fixed width in flex manner. This simply explains -

0 = don't grow (shorthand for flex-grow)

0 = don't shrink (shorthand for flex-shrink)

75px = start at 75px (shorthand for flex-basis)

Plunkr here - https://plnkr.co/edit/v7ww6DhJ6zCaPyQhPRE8?p=preview

Comment: Nice.Both works. Thank you. But If data is more its going beyond the table also. And word-wrap also not working

Comment: why do you use [ngClass] instead of normal class?

Comment: @Rahul is there any way to define same size for the column even screen size changes? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65296518/how-to-support-same-column-size-when-screen-size-reducing-in-angular-material-ta

Answer (score 38):

If you are using **angular/flex-layout** in your project, you can set column with by adding **fxFlex** directive to mat-header-cell and mat-cell:

```
 <ng-container matColumnDef="name" >
      <mat-header-cell fxFlex="100px" *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Name</mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell  fxFlex="100px" *matCellDef="let row;" (click)="rowClick(row)">{{row.Name}}</mat-cell>
 </ng-container>
```

Otherwise, you can add custom CSS to achieve the same result:

```
.mat-column-name{
    flex: 0 0 100px;
}
```

Comment: is there any way to define same size for the column even screen size changes? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65296518/how-to-support-same-column-size-when-screen-size-reducing-in-angular-material-ta

Comment: Maybe try with css  .mat-column-EXAMPLE {max-width: 120px; min-width: 120px;  overflow-wrap: break-word; word-wrap: break-word;}

Answer (score 20):

Check this: https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/5808

Since material2 is using flex layout, you can just set `fxFlex="40"` (or the value you want for fxFlex) to `md-cell` and `md-header-cell`.

Comment: It is worth pointing out that `fxFlex="40px"` is also possible

Comment: Simplest way to do this. Good tip!

Answer (score 15):

I found a combination of jymdman's and Rahul Patil's answers is working best for me:

```
.mat-column-userId {
  flex: 0 0 75px;
}
```

Also, if you have one "leading" column which you want to always occupy a certain amount of space across different devices, I found the following quite handy to adopt to the available container width in a more responsive kind (this forces the remaining columns to use the remaining space evenly):

```
.mat-column-userName {
  flex: 0 0 60%;
}
```

Comment: This is the best answer.

Answer (score 14):

The [Angular material documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples) uses

```
.mat-column-userId {
    max-width: 40px;
}
```

for its table component to change the column width. Again, userId would be the cells name.

Answer (score 10):

I'm using FlexLayout to update the column width according query media that FlexLayout gives us.

```
fxFlex="30" fxFlex.gt-xs="15" fxFlex.gt-sm="20" fxFlex.gt-md="25"
```

means that this column will use the 30% of the row width by default, when gt-xs @mediaQuery is met, the new width will be 15% and similar behavior for other conditions

```
<!-- CURRENTBALANCE COLUMN-->
  <ng-container cdkColumnDef="balance_2">
    <mat-header-cell fxFlex="30" fxFlex.gt-xs="15" fxFlex.gt-sm="20"
       fxFlex.gt-md="25" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center center"
       *cdkHeaderCellDef>{{ balanceTable.datesHeaders[2] }}</mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell fxFlex="30" fxFlex.gt-xs="15" fxFlex.gt-sm="20" fxFlex.gt-md="25" 
      *cdkCellDef="let eventTop">
      <div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
        <!-- CELL_CONTENT-->
      </div>
    </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>
<!-- CURRENTBALANCE COLUMN-->
```

> Read more about FlexLayout and @MediaQueries at https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/Responsive-API

Comment: Adding the fxFlex directive to one column seems to effect them all. Is there a way to target only one column?

Answer (score 6):

I just used:

```
th:nth-child(4) {
    width: 10%;
}
```

Replace 4 with the position of the header that you need to adjust the width for.The [examples in the documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples) used:

```
td, th {
  width: 25%;
}
```

So I just modified it to get what I wanted.

Answer (score 4):

You can set the .mat-cell class to flex: 0 0 200px; instead of flex: 1 along with the nth-child.

```
.mat-cell:nth-child(2), .mat-header-cell:nth-child(2) {
    flex: 0 0 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can now do it like this

```
<cdk-cell [style.flex]="'0 0 75px'">
```

Answer (score 4):

you can using `fxFlex` from "@angular/flex-layout" in `th` and `td` like this:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="value">
      <th mat-header-cell fxFlex="15%" *matHeaderCellDef>Value</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" fxFlex="15%" fxLayoutAlign="start center">
                           {{'value'}}
            </td>
       </th>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
.mat-column-skills {
    max-width: 40px;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure, that this deviates from the top voted answer? Probably your cdkColumnDef is just different?

Comment: no thats pretty much same, just wanted to highlight , that only this worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the element selectors:

```css
mat-header-cell:nth-child(1), mat-cell:nth-child(1) {
    flex: 0 0 64px;
}
```

But [jymdman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45430287/1951524) is the most recommended way to go in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

Sample Mat-table column and corresponding CSS:

**HTML/Template**

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
     Wider Column Header
  </mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let displayData">
    {{ displayData.value}}
  </mat-cell>`enter code here`
</ng-container>
```

**CSS**

```
.mat-column-courtFolderId {
    flex: 0 0 35%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the very easy solution for this - setting different width for column in style sheet by overriding the both cell and header cell:

Example - setting custom width for 1st and 5th column:

```css
.mat-cell:nth-child(1),
.mat-header-cell:nth-child(1) {
  flex: 0 0 5%;
}
.mat-cell:nth-child(5),
.mat-header-cell:nth-child(5) {
  flex: 0 0 10%;
}
```

[github](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/5808)

Answer (score 0):

You can also add the styling directly in the markup if you desire so:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="Edit">
     <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef > Edit </th>
     <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" (click)="openModal()" style="width: 50px;"> <i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i> </td>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have too many table column and it is not adjusted in angular table using `md-table`, then paste the following style in `component.css` file. It will work like a charm with scroll view horizontally.

> ```css
> .mat-table__wrapper .mat-table {
>     min-width: auto !important;
>     width: 100% !important; }
>
> .mat-header-row {
>     width: 100%; }
>
> .mat-row {
>     width: 100%;
> }
> ```

Add this style to alter your column separately.

> ```css
> .mat-column-{colum-name} {
>     flex: 0 0 25% !important;
>     min-width: 104px !important;
> }
> ```

Alternatively check [this link](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/9874), *(where the code above came from)*, for more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take an example. If your table has columns as follows:

```
<!-- ID Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="id" >
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> ID </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.sid}} </td>
  </ng-container>

 <!-- Name Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Name </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.name}} </td>
  </ng-container>
```

As this contain two columns. then we can set the width of columns using

```
.mat-column-<matColumnDef-value>{
    width: <witdh-size>% !important;
}
```

for this example, we take

```
  .mat-column-id{
    width: 20% !important;      
  }
  .mat-column-name{
    width: 80% !important;
  }
```