# Angular material - table - change column width

Tags: angular, angular-material

is there any way how to set different width for column ?

After many tries, it seems columns are even, ignoring all styles.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [md-table - How to update the column width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45159066/md-table-how-to-update-the-column-width)

Answer (score 8):

yes, it is possible using css `.mat-column-<matColumnDef-value>`, suppose you have a column def "group" like:

```
<!-- Group Column -->
<ng-container matColumnDef="group">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Group</mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
    {{element.group}}
  </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```

In the css you can set the width:

```
.mat-column-group {
  width: 150px;
  max-width: 150px;
}
```

Comment: is there any way to define same size for the column even screen size changes? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65296518/how-to-support-same-column-size-when-screen-size-reducing-in-angular-material-ta

Answer (score 0):

this is awkward, it is not possible to override styles by `width`... `min-width` has to be applied.